# How to set zero instead of null

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datagridview

Using VB.Net

I want to make a datagird cell value zero instead of null

For example

Datagridview1

```
Id value1 value2 value3

01 null null 0
02 0 null 10
03 100 null 100
...
```

Expected output

```
Id value1 value2 value3

01 0 0 0
02 0 0 10
03 100 0 100
...
```

I have more than 80 columns and 100 rows, instead of checking the cell one by one any other method is available

Tried Code

```
    Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If CInt(e.Value) = 0 Then
                e.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above code is not working properly, when i add the details in datagridview from database, showing null cell also.

How to make zero instead of null.  Any other method or suggestion

Need VB.Net code help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Right-Click the DatagridView and click on Properties.
- In the Property window, locate DefaultCellStyle
- Click on the Tab
- In the Dialog that appear, specify the NullValue

[image]

You can also set it from code

> **dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = 0;**
>
> Gets or sets the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView cell display value corresponding
>   to a cell value of System.DBNull.Value or null.